# How can I create a dialog in SAX that lets a user choose one item from a recordset?

Tags: sax, recordset

I am new to programming.

I'm trying to write a *macro* in a program called Captovation Capture. Basically this program is for scanning documents (usually forms of some kind), and then *indexing* them (by typing in *metadata* into fields).

We currently use some *macros* (that were written by someone else) that will automatically fill some of the fields based on data entered in another field.

For example, you can enter in an employee's (unique) number into the *EMPLOYEE NUMBER* field, and the macro will query our database using the number, and then automatically fill in the employee's first and last name, department, etc.

I'm writing a *macro* like this that could return multiple results, and I need to allow the user to see the list of possible matches and then choose the correct one.

All I know about the *macros* is what's in the help file: "Captovation Capture supports a Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) compatible programming language for writing and debugging macros."

**Edit 20150315**: OP subsequently determined the code would be written in SAX not VBA.

So at this point, I am able to query the database and get a **ADODB.Recordset** object populated with the results, I just don't know how to display those results to the user, and let them choose one.

EDIT: Here is a snippet of the code I have so far.

```
If (Len(FieldValue) > 0 And InStr(1, "VendorName", FieldName)) Then
  Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
  Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim ConnectStr As String

  ConnectStr = "XXXXXXXXX"

  conn.Open (ConnectStr)
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

  cmd.CommandText = "select XXXX from XXX where XXX like '" & FieldValue & "' and XXX = 'C' and XXX IS NULL"
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

'MsgBox cmd.CommandText

Set rst = cmd.Execute()

If rst Is Nothing Then
  Exit Sub
End If

If rst.Fields(0) = 0 Then
  MsgBox("VendorGID Not Found, Please check the Vendor Name")
  mctlIndex.SetFieldValue "VendorGID", ""
  Exit Sub
End If

'At this point, this code assumes that there is exactly 1 result from the query
'but I need some code here to present all the results and let the user choose one.

mctlIndex.SetFieldValue "VendorGID", rst.Fields(0).Value
rst.Close
```

After adding a UserDialog, this code was generated:

```
Begin Dialog UserDialog 400,203 ' %GRID:10,7,1,1
      ListBox 30,21,350,35,ListArray(),.ListBox1
End Dialog
Dim dlg As UserDialog
Dialog dlg
```

How do I populate the ListBox with the contents of the Recordset?

Comment: Does your VBA environment support userforms?  You could use a combo or listbox to disply the returned records on a form, so the end-user can make a selection.

Comment: Hi Tim, and thanks for responding.  That is a great question, and I have no idea what the answer is.  :)  How can I tell if my VBA environments supports userforms?  (Sorry, again, I clearly have no idea what I'm doing!)

Comment: In the VB Editor is there an `Insert >> UserForm` menu item?

Comment: OK, we're making progress, I think!  I don't have an "Insert >> UserForm" menu item, but I do have a "Dialog" button in the toolbar.  When I click it, I get a "UserDialog Editor" which lets me design what I HOPE is a userform.  I placed a single listbox control on the userform, clicked "save and exit" and some code was generated.  I will put it in my main post.  So... now what?  Thank so much for your help!

Comment: No idea what's next - that's not how it works in the other (Office) VBA environment I'm familiar with.  Don you have any docs/Help files for this?

Comment: @user3357334 Hard to tell what you have there... it looks like you may have some odd vba implementation that lets you see some code that is usually generated by the designer and hidden from view.  You could try populating the listbox associated with that dialog by using `dlg.ListBox1.List =` from your module to see if that does anything, but if it were me I'd just insert my own user form, place a listbox on it, and a button to continue, and set it up from that.

Comment: So it turns out that I'm using an implementation of VBA called "Sax Basic."  Once I found out how to access the help files (strangely, the help file was not available via any button or menu, I had to press the F1 key to pull it up) I was able to muddle my way through this.  Basically, the ONLY way to populate the ListBox is when you create it; you point it to a array of strings, and that's what it uses to populate the list.  So my crude solution was to keep "MoveNext"ing through the recordset until I hit "EOF" and saving each result into an array, and then using that to create the ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

"So it turns out that I'm using an implementation of VBA called "Sax Basic." Once I found out how to access the help files (strangely, the help file was not available via any button or menu, I had to press the F1 key to pull it up) I was able to muddle my way through this. Basically, the ONLY way to populate the ListBox is when you create it; you point it to a array of strings, and that's what it uses to populate the list. So my crude solution was to keep "MoveNext"ing through the recordset until I hit "EOF" and saving each result into an array, and then using that to create the ListBox." –  [user3357334](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3357334/user3357334)

Community wiki. Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.